Why won't my ASUS TUF Gaming X570-PLUS boot with a FireWire PCIe card installed?
My PC has the ASUS TUF Gaming X570-PLUS motherboard (ACPI BIOS Revision 1404). Has functioned fine for the 2 years since built. I am going to be doing some transfer of legacy Mini DV tapes from a camcorder via Firewire.
When the FireWire PCIe card is installed, the computer comes on, but will not even boot to/past BIOS.
Troubleshooting:

When the FireWire card is removed, the PC functions as normal. Place card back in and same thing happens.
Changed which PCIe slot I place the FireWire card into. No difference.
Cannot locate any BIOS references to FireWire.

I understand that maybe the new card itself is bad, but would it just not work if that was the case.
The FireWire PCIe card is this one: “PCIe Firewire Card for Windows 10, IEEE 1394A PCI Express Controller 4 Ports(3 x 6 Pin and 1 x 4 Pin), 1394a Firewire 400 Adapter for Windows 7/8/11/Mac OS with Low Profile Bracket and Cable”
System information is:

Edition: Windows 11 Pro Version
23H2 Installed on ‎3/‎17/‎2024
OS build  22631.4602
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22700.1055.0
Monitor: BenQ SW2700
Audio: Realtek Digital Output
HD: Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB
HD: Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB
HD: ST1000DM003-1ER162
HD: WDC WD2003FZEX-00SRLA0
Display: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti
Mouse/Keyboard: Logitech
Controllers: Standard SATA AHCI
Processors: AMD Ryzen 7 3800X 8-Core
Motherboard: ASUS TUF Gaming X570-Plus (ACPI BIOS Revision 1404)


Can you clarify if the a "Firewire PCIe card" is used, rather than a "Firewire PCI card" is used? As far as I can tell the ASUS TUF Gaming X570-PLUS only has PCIe slots.

Doesn't seem like it would be the problem, but I see "Installing other devices when using PCIe RAID Mode may cause your PC to fail to boot up." under the subhead "PCIEX16_1 Bandwidth" setting in section "3.6.5 Onboard Devices Configuration" in the manual.

Interesting related discussion on this issue: ( https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217994 ) it's regarding the Linux kernel but the specific combo of hardware and chipset(s) is, basically what is at play here (see last in thread especially).

Yorik, I am not using RAID so this would not apply, correct? Another person mentioned that changes may be necessary to CSM (Compatibility Support Module). Makes sense, I enabled CMS with no other changes & results the same. I am not sure what other changes to make under CMS? I have an image of the manual & the CMS page of the BIOS here:
https://brucevarner.com/picts/ASUS%20CMS.jpg

@B.Varner - Enabling CMS is the reason Windows is not able to boot, Windows does not support, Legacy Mode. If the card requires it then there is absolutely no way to support it on a modern Windows 11 machine

OK, could you clarify? I enabled CMS. It did still not allow the Firewire card to work but, when the card was not in the PC, the computer booted & works fine. Even with CMS enabled.  What am I missing?
